# What security benefit does the Same Origin policy provide beyond security by obscurity?

Tags: javascript, http, security, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy

I'm struggling to see what security benefits the Same Origin policy provides when browsers only restrict cross domain XMLHttpRequests.

Let's look at a pretty good explanation of the security benefits of the same origin policy: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/8269

Summarizing what is written in that SO answer, the same origin policy prevents a malicious website from executing XMLHttpRequests that could have side effects on an external domain. For example, it prevents a malicious website from executing a transaction on a bank website that you are logged onto via an XMLHttpRequest object.

But can't those same HTTP requests be executed in another way that doesn't violate the same origin policy restrictions?

For example, to do an HTTP GET request on another domain (an external domain), I could use JSONP or a similar technique where I use Javascript to set the src attribute of an HTML element to the desired URL of the external domain. This would force the browser to do a GET request on this external domain and that GET request, as with all HTTP requests, would include in its headers the cookie data for that external domain.

As another example, to do a POST request I could create hidden form elements with Javascript and trigger the submission of that form to an external domain. Again, external domain specific cookie data would be passed in the POST request.

So my question is what am I missing... what's the point of the Same Origin policy if its security benefits can be easily bypassed?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/72569/911 is a better answer.

Comment: That's a nice question for security.SE. Here on SO it's off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Same-Origin Policy prevents you from *reading responses* from a different domain.

As you've discovered, nothing prevents you from *sending requests* to a different domain, which is why CSRF vulnerabilities exist.

In fact, the defense against that (CSRF tokens) only works because the Same-Origin Policy prevents you from stealing tokens from other domains.

Comment: Could I not create an iframe pointing to an external domain and then get the contents of that iframe with javascript? Isn't that essentially getting the response data?

Comment: @VKK: No; that's exactly what the Same-Origin Policy prevents you from doing.

Answer (score 2):

The [SOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) does not prevent you from sending requests (with credentials), it prevents you from accessing the response data. To secure submissions, [CSRF tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) need to be used.

Comment: Same as my comment above: Could I not create an iframe pointing to an external domain and then get the contents of that iframe with javascript? Isn't that essentially getting the response data?

Comment: @VKK No, the SOP policy also prevents you from accessing the contents of foreign (i)frames. Or even image data of canvase to which foreign images were painted. If you find a way around, it's a browser bug - and a quite valuable zero-day :-)